# How do I get a dataflow Job ID from within the pipeline or before the pipeline ran?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I want to grab the dataflow's Job ID as a string before actually running the pipeline or inside of it.

As an example let's say I have this:

```
DataflowOptions options = optionsConst.getOptions();         
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
String jobID = doSomthing(); <-- I'd like to grab the job id here

PCollection<KV<String, Object>> refData = p.apply("BigTable Access", BigtableIO.read()
                .withProjectId(options.getBigtableProjectId())
                .withInstanceId(options.getBigtableInstanceId())
                .withTableId(options.getLookupTableId()))
                .apply("Keep tags valid versions", ParDo.of(new MethodThatDoesSomethingWithJobID(**jobId**))); <-- Or inside this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible to do that, as the Job Id is created once you start to run it. What you can do is to save the output once you start run the pipeline, or to return the [list job running](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-command-line-intf#jobs_commands)

Comment: you can also give the job a job name in the PipelineOptions, but that won't be the Job ID, as Ramses correctly points out.